# JQuery - Deleting HTML Created with .clone

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

All,

I have a chunk of HTML that I am using as my source for the JQuery `.clone()` method. Included in the HTML chunk is a "delete" icon which upon clicking should remove the copied HTML chunk but it does not.

I am probably not selecting the copied element correctly but I am not certain.

Thanks

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAgS7/1/)

Here is the code:

**The HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <h2>Sponsors Section</h2>
    <form action="" id="myForm">
     <div id="addCosponsorSection" style="width:900px; margin-left:12px;">
        <div id="cosponsors">
            <span class="formColumn1"><label for="sponsorclubname1">Sponsor club name 1:</label></span>
            <span class="formColumn2"><input  type="text" id="cosponsorcontact" name="cosponsorcontact"  placeholder="Name" title="Co-sponsor contact" /></span>
            <span class="formColumn3"><input  type="text" id="cosponsoremail"  name="cosponsoremail"     placeholder="Email" title="Co-sponsor email" /></span>
            <span class="formColumn4"><input  type="text" id="cosponsorphone"  name="cosponsorphone"     placeholder="Phone" title="Co-sponsor phone" /></span>
      </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
        <p>
          <span class="js-add-cosponsor-hyperlink">+ cosponsor</span>
        </p>   
     </form>




<!-- Start Add Co-Sponsor Row Template -->
<div style="display:none">
        <div id="cosponsorsTemplate">
            <span class="formColumn1"><label>Sponsor club name</label></span>
            <span class="formColumn2"><input  type="text" id="cosponsorcontact" name="cosponsorcontact"  placeholder="Name" title="Co-sponsor contact" /></span>
            <span class="formColumn3"><input  type="text" id="cosponsoremail"  name="cosponsoremail"     placeholder="Email" title="Co-sponsor email" /></span>
            <span class="formColumn4"><input  type="text" id="cosponsorphone"  name="cosponsorphone"     placeholder="Phone" title="Co-sponsor phone" /><a class="icon delete"></a></span>
      </div>
</div>    
<!-- End Add Co-Sponsor Row Template -->
```

**The JS**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var uniqueId = 1;
        $(function () {
            $('.js-add-cosponsor-hyperlink').click(function () {

                var copy = $("#cosponsorsTemplate").clone(true).appendTo("#addCosponsorSection").hide().fadeIn('slow');
                var cosponsorDivId = 'cosponsors_' + uniqueId;
                copy.attr('id', cosponsorDivId);

               var deleteLink = $(this).find('.icon delete');
                deleteLink.click(function () {
                    copy.fadeOut(300, function () { $(this).remove(); }); //fade out the removal

                });

                $('#' + cosponsorDivId).find('input').each(function () {
                    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '_' + uniqueId);
                    $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + '_' + uniqueId);



                });

                uniqueId++;
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$(this).find('.icon delete');` looks wrong... shouldn't you be finding the delete button inside the clone rather than inside the clicked button that created the clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
var deleteLink = $(this).find('.icon delete');
```

to this:

```
var deleteLink = copy.find(".icon.delete");
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently attempting to select a delete icon within the `+ cosponsor` link. You need to select the actual copy of the template element.

I had success by defining the copied element as its own variable. That way, you can select elements within the element that was copied.

```
var thecopy=copy.attr('id', cosponsorDivId);
```

I also replaced your `click()` handler with `on()`:

```
var deleteLink = thecopy.find('a.icon.delete');

deleteLink.on('click',function () {
    copy.fadeOut(300, function () { $(this).remove(); }); //fade out the removal
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zAgS7/2/